# Bibliography showing up in reverse

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

I am using Overleaf and I have a main tex file and a bib file titled 'biblio.bib' where I store the citations for a report. However, my citations are showing up in reverse. As an example, my LaTeX document is like the following:

```
This is the text which precedes the first citation \cite{First citation}. Then, moving on we have the second citation \cite{Second citation}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
```

However, the output comes out as

```
This is the text which precedes the first citation [2]. Then, moving on we have the second citation [1]
```

The citations are still correct, but they are being labelled in the wrong order.

Comment: plain style outputs in alphabetical order of author names. You haven't shown enough information to know if the output you get is expected or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` instead. That will ensure the references are listed and labeled by the order of appearance.

Answer (score 0):

The `plain` style sorts the reference list **by alphabetical order of the first author’s last name**. If you prefer a scheme where the numerical citation labels are numbered sequentially throughout the text, you’ll have to choose a bibliography style which implements this. For example, as suggested above, you can use  \bibliographystyle{ieeetr} to get the desired output..